# Cronjob for specific hours

Tags: 12.04, server, power-management, cron

I need a cronjob with criteria to power on/off a TV on the basis:

Mon-Fri, power on the screen at 07.00 and power off the screen 17.00.
Friday after 17.00 to Monday morning to be powered off.

I'm using `xset` to force dpms on/off.

`DISPLAY=:0 xset dpms force off` (powers off the TV)

`DISPLAY=:0 xset dpms force on && DISPLAY=:0 xset s reset` (powers on the TV)

xset: /usr/bin/xset

Answer (score 1):

Well first I'd move your turn on/off logic into scripts:

Contents of `/usr/local/bin/tv-turnon`:

```
#!/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0 xset dpms force on && DISPLAY=:0 xset s reset
```

Contents of `/usr/local/bin/tv-turnoff`:

```
#!/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0 xset dpms force off
```

Make them runable

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/tv-turnon
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/tv-turnoff
```

And then setup cron to run them according to your schedule `crontab -e`

```
0 7 * * 1-5 /usr/local/bin/tv-turnon
0 17 * * 1-5 /usr/local/bin/tv-turnoff
```

(this will run in `vi` by default, if you're not familiar `i` to start inserting text `:wq` to save and exit)

Comment: This may have a better chances to succeed. I have experienced some kind of issues when trying to include command lines in the cron but when scripting it succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

```
00 17 * * 1-5 DISPLAY=:0 xset dpms force off

00 07 * * 1-5 DISPLAY=:0 xset dpms force on && DISPLAY=:0 xset s reset
```

Comment: You don't need to use twice `DISPLAY=:0` in this command: `DISPLAY=:0 xset dpms force on && DISPLAY=:0 xset s reset`. That because the value of `DISPLAY` remain the same after `xset dpms force on` had ran.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following entries in your crontab file:

```
0 7 * * 1-5 DISPLAY=:0 xset dpms force on && xset s reset
0 17 * * 1-5 DISPLAY=:0 xset dpms force off
```

To add a new entry in your crontab file, use the following command:

```
crontab -e
```

More about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron